# foreach loop returns zero results

Tags: php

I am pulling data from a json file and I get results no problem but I a only get 1 result. So when I do a foreach loop I get no results.

**json results:**

```
{
  "channels": [
    {
      "position": 4,
      "id": "901",
      "name": "Away"
    },
    {
      "position": 0,
      "id": "900",
      "name": "General"
    },
    {
      "position": 1,
      "id": "889",
      "name": "HQ"
    },
    {
      "position": 2,
      "id": "888",
      "name": "Base"
    }
  ],
}
```

I can echo out this:

```
echo $json_array['channels'][0]['position'];
echo $json_array['channels'][0]['id'];
echo $json_array['channels'][0]['name'];
```

But whatever I try I only get 1 result I do a foreach loop and it does nothing

```
foreach($json_array as $item) {

     echo $item['channels'][0]['position'];
     echo $item['channels'][0]['id'];
     echo $item['channels'][0]['name'];

 }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure you are looping through the correct array? Logic would tell me that you should be doing `foreach( $json_array['channels'] as $item ){ echo $item['position']; ...` but I can't be sure.

Comment: A better answer can flush this out, but try `echo $item[0]['position'];` and see if you can solve the problem. :)

Comment: *"Am i missing something?"* -- apparently you are missing basic understanding on how [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) work.

Comment: What you call $json_array is in fact a json_object, the array is the channels property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the value of first object only. `$json_array['channels']` is an array of objects, you need to loop over that objects. This should work:

```
foreach($json_array['channels'] as $item) {
    echo $item['position'];
    echo $item['id'];
    echo $item['name'];
}
```

To make it clear to understand, this is how it would work with a for loop:

```
for($index = 0; $index < count($json_array['channels']); $index++) {
    echo $json_array['channels'][$index]['position'];
    echo $json_array['channels'][$index]['id'];
    echo $json_array['channels'][$index]['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You missing collection iteration

```
foreach($json_array['channels'] as $item) {
    echo $item['position'];
    echo $item['id'];
    echo $item['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `foreach`, you can now access every element of array *channels* by variable `$item`

```
  foreach($json_array['channels'] as $item) {
     echo $item['position'];
     echo $item['id'];
     echo $item['name'];
 }
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 2):

You're telling your php that you want in your json file to go to ['channels'] and then take the first position [0]. So you're looping and it keeps hitting it at position 0. So you could do, as others said:

```
foreach($json_array['channels'] as $item) {
    echo $item['position'];
    echo $item['id'];
    echo $item['name'];
}
```

But to make it more clear to you, this is another working example:

```
$json = json_decode($json_string)
for($i = 0; $i < count($json['channels']) ; $i++)
{
    echo $json['channels'][$i]['position'];
    echo $json['channels'][$i]['id'];
    echo $json['channels'][$i]['name'];
}
```

Comment: Did you just copied all my content?